# Rescue data on a bad micro sd card

Tags: linux, data-recovery, sd-card

I have a micro SD card that was damaged, when putting in the reader of my computer, I got this

```
[65850.877706] mmc0: unrecognised CSD structure version 2
[65850.877719] mmc0: error -22 whilst initialising SD card
```

The card appear nowhere, and `file /dev/mmc0` give :

```
/dev/mmc0: cannot open `/dev/mmc0' (No such file or directory)
```

The card contain a lot of traveling pic that I would really like to get back... Anything i cant try to do?

(the microSD card is in a new adapter, the last one was probably faulty and broke the card..)
(on linux mint 18.3 64 bit)

Answer (score 1):

Steps I would perform:

- activate write protection on SD card
- create an image of the SD card
- create at least one copy of the image file
- use recovery software only on the copies of the image file

Create the image:

- e.g. on Linux with the command `dd if=/dev/mmc0 of=/path/to/your/image.img`
- safecopy http://safecopy.sourceforge.net/

List of software (collections) that I have used successfully for recovery:

- PhotoRec https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec
- Foremost http://foremost.sourceforge.net/
- CAINE http://www.caine-live.net/

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion, but the sd card does not even show up in /dev  :dd if=/dev/mmc0 of=saveimage.img
dd: impossible d'ouvrir '/dev/mmc0': Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type

Comment: Still there is hope, as this can be a problem with your card reader or the adapter. Maybe you can try a different (borrowed) adapter card that has proven to perfectly work with other micro SD cards?

Comment: I will try that in the morning (but the adapter is brand new) if it show's nothing with the other adapter, if I understand well, it's mean that there is no work around?

Comment: Unfortunately I do not know how to recover the data, if all adapters and card readers fail to give (at least raw) access to the card. Although image recovery apps for Android devices exist, I can not recommend any. Those I have tested simply did not work.